# Line of comma's appear in browser, but not written in .jsp file

Tags: java, html, jsp, netbeans

So I just tested my page and opened it in a browser, it displays a line of comma's and when I look in the inspector it shows that there is a line of comma's in my code, but when I open netbeans where I wrote the .jsp file, there are no comma's there.

- **In browser**

[image: In browser]

- **In netbeans**

[image: In netbeans]

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: at the end of your first `<td>` you have a comma

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: pretty small little things aren't they